# Windows 7 - Right-click context cascade menu for Python

Tags: python, windows, shell, cascade

I'm trying to add to context menu for *.zip files. To launch my python script with nessesary parameters.

I've added to register following keys:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WinZip\shell\SSSeracher] "MUIVerb"="SSSearcher Script" "SubCommands"="SSSearcher.Rule1;SSSearcher.Rule2;SSSearcher.Rule3;SSSearcher.Custom;SSSearcher.Config"
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Rule1] @="Rule #1"
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Rule1\command] @="C:\\APPS\\python\\Scripts\\sssearcher.py \"%1\" \"1\""
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Rule2] @="Rule #2"
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Rule2\command] @="C:\\APPS\\python\\Scripts\\sssearcher.py \"%1\" \"2\""
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Rule3] @="Rule #3"
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Rule3\command] @="C:\\APPS\\python\\Scripts\\sssearcher.py \"%1\" \"3\""
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Custom] @="Custom rule"
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Custom\command] @="C:\\APPS\\python\\Scripts\\sssearcher.py \"%1\" \"4\""
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Custom] @="Custom rule"
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Custom\command] @="C:\\APPS\\python\\Scripts\\sssearcher.py \"%1\" \"4\""
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Config] @="Config File"
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SSSearcher.Config\command] @="vim C:\\APPS\\python\\Scripts\\sssearcher.pyc"
```

As menu showing up clickin on those does absolutly nothing.

I've been following this tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**There is something that I missing, but unfortunately I cannot find answer what. Could you help me with that?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just followed these steps and it appears to work:

1) First find the `.zip` key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

2) Select it and look at its default. In my case the default is `CompressedFolder`:

[image]

3) Now navigate your way down to `CompressedFolder\shell` (or what was ever under your default for .zip) which is also contained under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`:

[image]

4) Right click on the shell and add a new key, in my case I've added a key named `MyCommand`. Add a subkey to this key called `command`. `MyCommand` will be the name of the command that appears on the context menu.

[image]

5) Next edit the value of the `(Deafult)` entry of the `command` subkey for `mycommand`, adding the operation you wish to perform. In my case I want to open a python file which tells me details about the file:

This is the python script:

```
import os
import sys

def main():
    st = os.stat(sys.argv[1])
    print st
    raw_input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And it is located at C:\info.py

And this is the entry I've added to default:

`python C:\\info.py %1`

[image]

That's all there is to it, now if you were to right click on a zip file you should see the command you've added:

[image]

Which when clicked gives:

[image]

Hope this is what you where after. If you wish to add more commands then just add more subkeys under the `shell` key as we did with `MyCommand`.

**UPDATE - CASCADING MENUS**

a) In order to add cascading menus navigate to the key stated above in step 3. In my case this is `CompressedFolder\shell` which is under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Once here add a key with a name of your choice, in my case I used `CascadeMenu`. Add 2 entries to this key:

- `MUIVerb` - this is the name that will appear for the cascade menu. In my case I have used `MyCascadeMenu`
- `SubCommands` - this is a semicolon separated list of commands. Name the commands whatever you like, in my case I have used `python.info`. Use a '|' between commands if you want a separator, for example `command1;|;command2`

[image]

b) Next we need to tell windows what this command actually does. Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\Shell`

Once here add a key with the name of your command. In my case the key is called `python.info`. Set the default value of the key to the name you want to appear in the context menu. In my case I have used `"File Info"`

[image]

c) Now add a subkey to your command, called `command`. Change the default entry of this command to the command you wish to execute. In my case I have set it to `python C:\\info.py %1`

[image]

d) We are now finished, right click on the .zip file to see your newly created context menu:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's working, i got it earier. But the thing is I really need that as a cascade menu. Too bad I cannot give screenshot here, cause dont remember my old account, and had to log here on FB acccount. :(

Comment: Ok @KonradKnitter I have updated the answer to inform you how to generate cascading menus. Is this what you were after?